# Could anyone explain what `concerned_with` is for and how to use it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Could anyone explain what `conererned_with` is for? I don't understand what the following code stands for.

```
concerned_with :stage, :format
```

Comment: Could you explain where you are seeing this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't anything standard in Ruby or Rails. Google turns up this old gem, however, which I'm guessing the code you're looking at uses: https://github.com/jakehow/concerned_with The README there describes what it does.